# Boost MPI : gather: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I wrote simple program to illustrate MPI gather. Each process send array of objects and root process receive that objects in vector. But, i got error:

```
*** glibc detected *** gather: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7464464 ***
BackTrace
......
MemoryMap
......
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/collectives.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::mpi;

class A
{
private:
    string x,y;
public:
    void setX(string x)
    {
        this->x=x;
    }
    void setY(string y)
    {
        this->y=y;
    }
    string getX()
    {
        return this->x;
    }
    string getY()
    {
        return this->y;
    }
    A()
    {

    }
    A(string x,string y)
    {
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;
    }
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>

    void serialize(Archive &ar,unsigned int version)
    {
        ar &x;
        ar &y;
    }


};



int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    environment env(argc,argv);
    communicator world;


    A p[2];

    p[0]=A("aa","aa");
    p[1]=A("bb","bb");

    vector<A> t;


    t.reserve(2*world.size());


    gather(world,p,2,t,0);

}
```

Does anyone know what is problem?
Thanks :) !

Comment: You should run it under valgrind and see what allocation/deallocation is offending

Comment: Thank you... Problem is in class... if i replace string mambers with int members, everything is ok..... How can I do gather with string members ? :)

Comment: Is the serialization even used (? I have no experience with Boost MPI; if the serialization method is a red herring, I can explain what's wrong: `std::string` is not POD)

Comment: According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/gather.html , "When the type T has an associated MPI data type, this routine invokes MPI_Gather to gather the values." and here : http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/mpi.pdf on page 13 Separating structure from content "However, variable-length data types such as strings and lists cannot be MPI data types." If anyone finds a good solution, tell me ! I guess @sehe is right.